# Adobe AIR 3.6 app using video camera crashes on Google Nexus 7 Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, air, adobe, android-camera

I am developing an AIR app for mobile devices which needs to access the video camera. So far it works great on iOS but on my Google Nexus 7 device the app crashes shortly after activating the video camera. I have set up the correct permissions and can access the 'front' camera on the device. Sometimes i see a quick flash of the video image which i add to the stage but then the app crashes and returns to the google nexus screen.

I am using -
Adobe AIR 3.6.0.6090 SDK
AS3 (obviously)
Google Nexus 7 running android 4.2.2

Has anyone noticed this behaviour? Is there anything I can change or is this an android / air bug?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think that this was only happening because I was remotely debugging the app. When I ran the app without the remote debugger it worked fine. video loaded and showed ok. Left this question here incase it saves anyone some time working out a similar problem :-)